# Replace the Toolbar for every Navigation Drawer fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have encountered this so-called [Collapsing Toolbar](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) of the new Material Design Support Library of Android, and I am considering applying this new design to some of my fragments.

So I also happen to arrive at this third-party library, [Material View Pager](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager), which is quite similar to a `Collapsing Toolbar`, except that it has a built-in `View Pager`. I so want to integrate it into my app because its functionality fits perfectly for a certain fragment. And because it is similar to a `Collapsing Toolbar`, it provides its own `Toolbar` that is needed to be set through `setSupportActionBar()`.

Moving on, from my code below, I have a `Navigation Drawer` that is held responsible for navigation between my five fragments *(COR, Class Schedule, Evaluation, INC Monitor & Clearance)*.

Now, I want this `Collapsing Toolbar` to be applied to two of my fragments *(COR & Clearance)*, and this `Material View Pager` to one fragment *(Evaluation)*. The problem is, I already have set a standard `Toolbar` for all of my fragments:

### toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/primary_dark"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation= "4dp" />
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public void setupToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}

public void setupNavigationDrawer() {
    drawer_layout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigation_view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            fragment_manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragment_transaction = fragment_manager.beginTransaction();
            fragment_transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

            menuItem.setChecked(true);

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.cor:   //Collapsing Toolbar here
                    fragment_transaction.replace(R.id.content, cor_fragment);
                    break;
                case R.id.sched: //Normal Toolbar here
                    fragment_transaction.replace(R.id.content, sched_fragment);
                    break;
                case R.id.eval:  //Material View Pager Toolbar here
                    fragment_transaction.replace(R.id.content, eval_fragment);
                    break;
                case R.id.inc:   //Normal Toolbar here
                    fragment_transaction.replace(R.id.content, inc_fragment);
                    break;
                case R.id.clear: //Collapsing Toolbar here
                    fragment_transaction.replace(R.id.content, clear_fragment);
                    break;
            }

            mHandler = new Handler();
            mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            int delay = 400;
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    fragment_transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragment_transaction.commit();
                }
            }, delay);

            drawer_layout.closeDrawers();

            return true;
        }
    });

    drawer_toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    };
    drawer_layout.setDrawerListener(drawer_toggle);
    drawer_toggle.syncState();

    drawer_layout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

As you could see from the comments above, for each fragment being loaded, I want to load a different toolbar. But in the code I wrote, I could only `setSupportActionBar()` one `Toolbar`. I tried putting `setSupportActionBar(toolbar_of_choice)` in every `case` of my `switch` statement, but it crashes the app.

So is there any workarounds in setting different toolbars for every fragment in my `Navigation Drawer`?

Comment: Did you ever get around this problem? As I am in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    fragment_manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment_transaction = fragment_manager.beginTransaction();
    fragment_transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

    menuItem.setChecked(true);

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.cor:   //Collapsing Toolbar here
            fragment_transaction.replace(R.id.content, cor_fragment);
            Toolbar toolbar =(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // use can replace original toolbar with collapsing//
            break;
        case R.id.sched: //Normal Toolbar here
            fragment_transaction.replace(R.id.content, sched_fragment);
Toolbar toolbar =(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarmain);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.eval:  //Material View Pager Toolbar here
            fragment_transaction.replace(R.id.content, eval_fragment);
            break;
        case R.id.inc:   //Normal Toolbar here
            fragment_transaction.replace(R.id.content, inc_fragment);
Toolbar toolbar =(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarmain);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.clear: //Collapsing Toolbar here
            fragment_transaction.replace(R.id.content, clear_fragment);
            break;
    }
```

Using the above code, you can easily utilise collapsing layout.